# USB Keyboard and Mouse no longer work after GRUB boot

Tags: boot, usb, keyboard, mouse

My USB keyboard and mouse don't work when booting into Ubuntu 12.04.

The keyboard is fine up until the boot loader (GRUB). I can select previous kernels or recovery mode. But regardless of the choice, once the boot progresses, both keyboard and mouse are no longer active.

Up until today it had been working fine - I've not made any changes to the system.

I seem to remember having a similar issue before, which had something to do with having a USB HDD connected in a previous session.

My mouse and keyboard are working in principle... great.

BUT! It takes 2-3 minutes after booting for these to be recognized. (Guess I was too impatient previously).

This certainly was not the case up until today.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am using a ubuntu 12.10 live CD. The keyboard works till GRUB, after that it doesn't respond even after completely booting up.

Answer (score 1):

Although this may not be for everyone, here's what i did to solve this problem. I put a PS2 keyboard and mouse into my computer. It works just fine.

Additionally, i installed a Synergy client on my Ubuntu, so that after i log in, i use the shared mouse and keyboard.

I hope this helps.

Love and peace,

Joe

---